# ¿Cómo iniciar el servicio MySQL en Windows?

Tags: windows, servicio, mysql-sever

Tengo instalado *MySQL Server 8.0*, y quiero iniciar el servicio *MySQL*.

Mi objetivo es iniciar el servicio para ver las tablas de un script *SQL* que tengo en mi disco duro. Nunca trabajé con *SQL*, de modo que en caso de iniciar el servicio tampoco sabría cómo ver las tablas, pero eso es otro tema. Tal archivo pesa 4 GB. Para eso intenté correr el script en **localhost**, intenté con varios puertos diferentes, pero sale **error 10061**.

Mirando en internet encontré que había que instalar el servicio *MySQL*. Cuando voy a mirar en el administrador de tareas, al iniciar el servicio, aparece *Iniciándose*, y luego de unos segundos dice, *Detenido*.

Otra alternativa que encontré es hacer esto en el *CMD* con permisos de administrador:

```
net start MySQL
```

La consola me dice lo siguiente:

> El servicio de MySQL está iniciándose.
> El servicio de MySQL no ha podido iniciarse.
>
> El servicio no informó de un error.
>
> Puede obtener más ayuda con el comando NET HELPMSG 3534.

Le hago caso, ejecuto `net helpmsg 3534` y aparece esto:

> El servicio no informó de un error.

¿Qué puede estar fallando? ¿Cómo ejecuto el servicio sin que se detenga?

---

**Notas:**

El *Windows* que tengo es un *Windows* normal, no es *Windows server*.

Para instalar *MySQL* descargué este enlace: https://cdn.mysql.com//Downloads/MySQLInstaller/mysql-installer-community-8.0.13.0.msi

Luego me pidió instalar *Python* y lo instalé en *64 bits*. Por último pude instalar todo correctamente.

Comment: anteriormente tenías algun otro gestor de bd corriendo en tu sistema?

Comment: ya revisaste estos 2 enlaces? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html y https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/starting-server.html

Comment: @shadow No recuerdo haber instalado otro gestor, pero tampoco estoy seguro de que esté instalado. Nop, no había leído esos enlaces, pero trataré de entenderlos, se ve complicado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero te debes dirigir a la siguiente página para descargar el `mysql_installer` que es una utilidad que me permite gestionar que productos `mysql_` requiero

https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/

Posterior elijo la versión que dice **16.3 MB**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora elijo la opción de *CUSTOM* para poder elegir que productos deseo bajar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Posterior del lado derecho elijo la versión que aparece por defecto disponible para mi SO

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora en la siguiente pantalla donde me indica que software es el que voy a descargar, doy click en `EXECUTE` en la parte inferior de la misma

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez que dicha descarga e instalación lleguen a 100%, tendré una nueva pantalla que dirá *READY TO CONFIGURE* donde debo dar clic en *NEXT*

Los demás pasos de configuración son conocidos para poner:

1. user: root
2. password:
3. port: 3306

El punto importante que si se debe aclarar es lo que aparece en la siguiente imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pues *MySQL 8* trae un nuevo método sistema de cifrado fuerte para contraseñas, yo personalmente elijo la segunda que es *Legacy* para que de este modo se asegure la compatibilidad con los drivers de conexión que actualmente existen para múltiples lenguajes; **pero esto ya es enteramente elección de quien instala**

**COMPROBACIÓN**

Al final desde el símbolo del sistema, procedemos a tratar de conectarnos así:

```
C:\Users\Slave>mysql -u root -p
Enter password: *****
```

Y si no existen contratiempos, el `prompt` debería cambiar a algo así

```
mysql>
```